# Call reloadData() after a dismissViewController

Tags: swift

I have a collectionView controller with a collectionView populated by a database. In this controller I have reloadData() in 'viewDidAppear' and 'viewWillAppear' functions.

The collectionView controller has a modal segue to a gameViewController. After the 'game' is finished in the gameViewController, the database is updated (this works) and the modal is dismissed back to the collectionView controller.

```
func gameOver() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

However despite 'viewDidAppear' and 'viewWillAppear' being called (I confirm this with a println()) when the gameViewController is dismissed, the collectionView data does not reload. So the updated database data isn't shown in the collectionView.

The collectionView data does reload if I dismiss the collectionView controller, and then reopen it.

How do I ensure the collectionView controller - reloadData() - is called after dismissing the gameViewController?

Code:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var collectionView: LevelsCollectionViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // code not related to question - creates game scene 
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

func gameOver() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}



class LevelsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

// code setting up cells

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    println("viewWillAppear")

    self.collectionView!.reloadData()
    self.collectionView!.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    println("viewDidAppear")
            self.collectionView!.reloadData()
    self.collectionView!.setNeedsDisplay()
}
}
```

UPDATE:

The println() viewWillAppear & viewDidAppear are printed in the console after the dismissViewController, but the collectonView data isn't reloaded.

The database that the collectionView is taken from is updated (done is another function called before gameOver().

I tried the method suggested below of having a reference to UIViewController and calling reloadData on that from viewDidDisappear, but nothing happens.

Comment: Is the object your view controller is reading from being updated with the new data? Some sample code might help.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? Im having the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some days I want to kick my own backside!

I 'stupidly' forgot to reload the temp array (levelProgress) that was holding the information taken from the database (held on array in appDelegate) in the collectionViewController.

Thus while the database and the array in appDelegate were being updated, the reloadData() was still working off the tempArray in the collectionViewController. Resetting this tempArray on viewDidAppear(), then reloadData() did the trick.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    levelProgress = appDelegate.levelProgress
    self.collectionView!.reloadData()
    self.collectionView!.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Think I'm going code blind

Answer (score 1):

Actually that's what the `completion` argument is for

```
func gameOver() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in
       self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your data source is being updated (a few println's in your `viewDidAppear()` will help) - in addition, try storing a reference to the collectionView controller and calling `reloadData()` on it in the `viewWillDisappear()` method of your gameViewController.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I believe the viewDidAppear() is being called as a put a println() in the fun and this is printed. It just seems that the collection view isn't being reloaded after the dismiss segue. I've updated my question above with more code, including your idea of calling reloadData() on viewWillDisappear

Comment: It sounds like fixing your data source was the issue!  Good eye.